# function inside a controller from view

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angular js this a book example .writer mentioned that on chaning funding it will display recommendation with multiple of 10 as you can see in the code. but we i compile this program no recommendation shown on the can .can some help me how   **$scope.computeNeeded** works..

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>this is title</title>
        <script src='angular.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<form ng-controller="StartUpController">
Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()" ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function StartUpController($scope) {
    $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
    $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
        $scope.needed = $scope.startingEstimate * 10;
    };
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: startingEstimate =0, so anything you multiply to 0, it will be same as 0*10 =0.

Comment: @Ved no user will enter starting estimate see the input box there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a simple mistake:

```
$scope.computeNeeded = function() {
$scope.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
};
```

and `{{funding.needed}}` should be

```
{{needed}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is displaying `funding.needed` (which is essentially `$scope.funding.needed`), but your function is modifying `$scope.needed` Also, your input is bound to `funding.startingEstimate`, but your function is accessing `$scope.startingEstimate`.

You need to access and modify the right thing:

```
$scope.computeNeeded = function() {
    $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey simi here is working fiddle for you please check demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndzy6hvj/)
Here is my html code

```
<div ng-app>
 <form ng-controller="StartUpController">
 Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()" ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
 Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
 </form>
</div>
```

And javascript code

```
function StartUpController($scope) {
    $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
    $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
        $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
    };
}
```